# Open file(Video) from external storage in local html (WebView) from assets folder? (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome, security, webview, uri

I'm using web project with VR functionality implemented via A-frame and three.js to display VR/360 content with some additional functionality, the whole web project is located in assets folder, and successfully displays 360 images/videos from project directory (HTML is "source src="**./default.mp4**" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"').

Target is to replace video source with URI from device external memory (downloads directory for example).

I've tried to use URI's in following formats :

Android standard :

**file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Trafalgar_Square_360.mp4**

URI formats found on StackOverflow :

**file:///storage/extSdCard/Download/Trafalgar_Square_360.mp4
file:///sdcard/downloads/Trafalgar_Square_360.mp4
file:///localhostpage/Download/Trafalgar_Square_360.mp4**

P.S. replacing vid URI to other from assets folder (example "**./other_vid.mp4**") works fine.

Hope you guys can give me some ideas on this topic, or at least explain if it's impossible.

Answer (score -1):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your Manifest file.

Comment: I've already had this permission, that's not a solution, but thanks anyway